# KnockoutJS Binding a list of objects from an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, knockout.js

I have a data-object in my Javascript code described as follows:

```
    //Data Object that represents products
    function Product(n, p, t, d) {
        this.name = ko.observable(n);
        this.price = ko.observable(p);
        tags = typeof (t) !== 'undefined' ? t : [];
        this.tags = ko.observableArray(tags);
        discount = typeof (d) !== 'undefined' ? d : 0;
        this.discount = ko.observable(discount);
        this.formattedDiscount = ko.computed(function ()
        { return (this.discount() * 100) + "%"; }
                                 ,this);
    }
```

Then, I have an AJAX call to retrieve data in JSON format

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "ShoppingCartExampleExample.aspx/SendData",
             data: "{}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (msg) {
                 alert(msg.d);               
             }
         });
     });
```

The AJAX call is working, I got this as result:

```
[
 {"Discount":0,
  "Name":"Chocolate",
  "Price":"7.99"
  "tags": ["Mars","Snickers"]
 },
 {"Discount":0.05,
  "Name":"Beer",
  "Price":"3.99"
 "tags": ["Large","Extra"]
 }
]
```

How could I map this list of objects received from an AJAX call to my Data-object?
I would like to map this list to an observable array and also map the tags array to an observable array, because I have a foreach binding that fills an HTML table to present the products and tags.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Knockout utility functions](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) are now included in the latest builds and are my preferred way of handling things. The mapping plugin is really overused at times and can make your objects more bloated than they need to be if not used correctly.

When your array of objects are returned, use the utility class:

```
var newProducts = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(dataItem) {
    return new Product(...);
});

ko.utils.arrayPushAll(myViewModel.products, newProducts);
```

Pretty straight forward and supported. You could even put the arrayMap directly into the arrayPushAll as the second parameter and skip declaring the newProducts variable.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming in your `success` function `msg.d` is your array. Just loop through the array and for each item call `new Product` for each item and then push the result into the observable array of whatever you parent view model is. For example, if you have something like:

```
var rootViewModel = function() {
    this.products = ko.observableArray();
    //... whatever other properties and functions you have
}

var myViewModel = new rootViewModel();
```

Then in your `success` function of your ajax call, you'd do something like:

```
success: function (msg) {
    msg.d.forEach(function(item) {
        myViewModel.products.push(new Product(item.Name, item.Price, item.tags. item.Discount));
    }             
}
```

Some of this plumbing can be avoided by using the [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin which is pretty configurable to allow you to map your plain javascript objects from your ajax call to whatever view model you want.